# swig ignore inherited function

Tags: python, swig

I'm using swig to generate python bindings to [YaST](https://github.com/yast/yast-python-bindings).
I'm adding functions to a parent class called YCPValue, via %extend.
Swig is also adding these parent class functions to children classes (YCPCode, for example). I don't want those parent class functions in the child, so I use %ignore to ignore each function. Except swig still includes the functions I %ignore. Is this because of the %extend on the parent class? Does anyone know if there is a way to still exclude these functions from the child?

```
%include <ycp/YCPValue.h>
%extend YCPValue {
    bool isCode() {
        return (*($self))->isCode();
    }
    YCPCode asCode() {
        return (*($self))->asCode();
    }
}

%include <ycp/YCPCode.h>
%ignore YCPCode::isCode();
%ignore YCPCode::asCode();
```

The idea here is, I might be returned a YCPValue type, and then have to use the isCode() function to see what it is, and asCode() to return the type as a YCPCode object. But if I'm returned the YCPCode object, then I don't want to have these extra functions (because it muddies the pydocs, etc). There are more child classes involved here also, this is just one example.

Comment: I think what I'm encountering is not a swig problem, but a feature of python https://medium.com/@george.shuklin/why-you-cant-remove-parent-methods-in-python-d4935e6d54a4

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is the following

```
%extend SomeChild {
// Your C++ extenstion...
bool isCode() {
    return (*($self))->isCode();
}
// Next your python extension
%pythoncode %{
if _newclass:
  __swig_dir__ = __swig_getmethods__.copy()
  __swig_dir__.update(__swig_setmethods__)
  __swig_dir__ = list(__swig_dir__.keys())
  __swig_dir__.remove('asCode')
def __dir__(self):
  return SomeChild.__swig_dir__
%}
};
```

This is not the most elegant solution, but I have used these overloads earlier on for filtering out functions, which are not intended to be called.